# why does the css font-family changes on other computers?

Tags: html, css, github

I am developing a website using the font Karla, when I pushed into Github to my team members, the font karla didn't work, they had to install karla font style on their computers to work with it. Is there any solution for this kind of poblems

Comment: How is the computer supposed to display a font that it doesn't have access to?

Comment: I thought there would be a way to install it on the site before deploying the platform. It would be unpractical to tell all visitors to install Karla font if you want the website to look fancy on your computer, I m the one losing here